# Solving Systems of ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on the following problems. However, I am unsure how to solve problem (b).

[image]

So far my attempt is to plug in $x_1 = ake^{kt}$ and $x_2 = bke^{kt}$ so then I get this after row-reduction:

$2e^{kt} = \dfrac{K}{3} - k$.

$e^{kt} = \dfrac{-k}{3}$.

However, I'm not sure where to go from here and I'm pretty sure I did something wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you mention source of this problem ,so that i may able to solve all of them ?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that 
$$\left[\matrix{ x_1 \\ x_2 \matrix}\right] = \left[\matrix{ 2 \\ 1 \matrix}\right] e^{kt}$$

The LHS is
$$\left[\matrix{x_1' \\ x_2'}\right] = \left[\matrix{2k \\ k}\right]e^{kt}$$

The RHS is
$$ \left[\matrix{-2 & -2 \\  1 & -5}\right]\left[\matrix{x_1 \\ x_2}\right] = \left[\matrix{-2 & -2 \\  1 & -5}\right]\left[\matrix{2 \\ 1}\right] e^{kt} = \left[\matrix{-6 \\ -3} \right]e^{kt} $$

Therefore
$$ \left[\matrix{ 2k \\ k \matrix} \right] = \left[\matrix{ -6 \\ -3 } \right]$$

or $k = -3$

**General solution:** 
The equation
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left[\matrix{x_1 \\ x_2}\right] = \textbf{A} \left[\matrix{x_1 \\ x_2}\right]$$

where $\textbf{A}$ is an arbitrary matrix, has the solution of the form
$$ \left[\matrix{x_1 \\ x_2}\right] = \left[ \matrix{ a \\ b } \right]e^{kt}$$

Substituting gives
$$ \textbf{A}\left[ \matrix{ a \\ b } \right] = k\left[ \matrix{ a \\ b } \right]$$

For this to hold, the vector $[a, b]^T$ must be an eigenvector of the matrix $\textbf{A}$ and $k$ is its eigenvalue

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me solve the rest of the problem?

I have a paradoxical answer for part c which says that $k = -4 \& k = -6$. Where did I go wrong? 

Also, I do not understand what part (d) is asking for.

Comment: You're getting there! Part (c) has no solution because the vector multiplied by $e^{kt}$ must have a very specific form. I edited my answer, hope that helps :)

Comment: Part (c) most certainly has a solution; the answer is $k = -4$.

Also, I am unsure how to solve part (d) of my question given that I've solved the rest of the problem. I do not even understand what the question is asking.

Comment: You're right, the answer is $-4$ for part (c). I suspect you have an algebra mistake somewhere.

Comment: For part (d), I think they just mean the general form of the solutions to (b) and (c)
$$x_1 = Ae^{kt}$$ $$x_2 = Be^{kt}$$

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand why you are taking $ a $ and $ b $. Since it is given that $$\begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 1 \end{bmatrix} e^{kt}$$ is a solution to $$\begin{bmatrix} x'_1\\ x'_2 \end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix} -2&-2\\ 1&-5 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}$$It is clear that $ x_1=2e^{kt} $ and $x_2=e^{kt}$.Then $ 2ke^{kt}=-6e^{kt} $ which gives $ k=-3$

Comment: i do not understand how you get $ke^{kt} = -4e^{kt}$. Please explain.

Comment: I substituted the solution in the equation.

Comment: $k = -4$ is incorrect; I tried it as an answer and it is not correct.

You have to explain how $x_1 = e^{kt} = x_2$; please explain how this works.

Comment: You are already given the solutions.  I just plugged them in the equation.

Comment: Okay but how did you plug them into the equation? I am here to learn which requires a demonstration of the steps that you took.

Comment: @letsmakemuffinstogether See the answer now..

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me solve the rest of the problem?

I have a paradoxical answer for part c which says that $k = -4 \& k = -6$. Where did I go wrong? 

Also, I do not understand what part (d) is asking for.