# Solving a system of 1st-order ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to understand what question (d) is asking for.

[image]

As I understand the question, it looks like they are asking for a linear combination of solutions (with arbitrary constants) which solves the system of linear equations.

So my idea is to set $x_1 = Ae^{-3t}$ and $x_2 = Be^{-4t}$ which I have deduced from my previous work. Is this correct or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Why do you post an exercise twice ? duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1327134/solving-systems-of-odes

Comment: Because it is a different question, within the same exercise, that I'm asking.

Comment: You can ask one of the .respondents.

Comment: I have but I haven't received any responses for quite some time. Would you perhaps be able to help me?

Comment: Just wait a few minutes. Im too tired. It´s late here in germany. Good luck.

Comment: K, no problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

From your previous work, you have two solutions to the system

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-2 & -2\\ 1 & -5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2 \end{bmatrix};
\end{equation}
namely,
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}2\\1 \end{bmatrix}e^{-3t}\quad\text{and}\quad \begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \end{bmatrix}e^{-4t}.
\end{align}

Check that the Wronskian is non-zero, so in fact these two solutions form a *fundamental set* of solutions for the system. This means that the general solution $\begin{bmatrix}x_1(t)\\x_2(t) \end{bmatrix}$ can be written as a *linear combination* of the two previously found solutions:

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}x_1(t)\\x_2(t) \end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}2\\1 \end{bmatrix}e^{-3t} + B\begin{bmatrix}1\\1 \end{bmatrix}e^{-4t}.
\end{equation}
Then $x_1(t) = \ldots$ and $x_2(t) = \ldots$